# React bootstrap conditionally render based on map index

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm creating a 4 column grid with react-bootstrap and would like to render a `<Row>` tag every idx%4==0 iteration, and a `</Row>` every idx%4==3 iteration

```
render(){

   {items.map( (item, idx) => (
       idx%4==0? <Row> : '' 

       <Col key={item} lg={3}>
            ....
       <Col>

       idx%4==3? </Row> : ''

    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this? I can't seem to do an opening tag  all by itself without a closing tag

Or should I slice 4 at a time and try to render that?

Comment: Yes, doing things this way is fine

Comment: it does not work - it doesn't like just one tag <Row> - needs a closing </Row>

also the syntax has an error which I'm requesting help on.

Comment: Oh hang on I misunderstood you, no you can't render JSX tags without closing them

Comment: @Ryan just wrote you an answer, let me know if that helps you out.

Comment: Maybe try Fragments instead of the empty quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `Col` array first and then in second iteration create Rows

```js
render() {
    const cols = items.map( (item, idx) => ( 

       <Col key={item} lg={3}>
            ....
       <Col>
       );
       
    const noRows =  Math.ceil(items.length / 4);

    const rows = Array.from(Array(noRows)).map((n, i) =>(
      <Row>
       {cols.slice(i* 4, (i + 1)* 4)}
      </Row>
    ));

    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed - and is a little bit easier to read than the reduce() answer.

Comment: Awesome, if you have lodash dependency, then `_.range(noRows),map()` will reduce a little bit code :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the right idea.  You can clean it up by using your index check `&&` to conditionally render instead of the ternary -

```
{items.map( (item, idx) => (
   {idx % 4 == 0 && <Row>}

     <Col key={item} lg={3}>
        ....
     <Col>

   {idx % 4 == 3 && </Row>}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to organize your syntax and ternary operators like this so you have a better picture of what's going on:

```
render(){
  {items.map((item, idx) => {
    return(
      idx % 4 == 0 ? (
        <Row>
          <Col>Hello</Col>
        </Row>
      ) : (
        idx % 4 == 3 ? (
          <Row>
            <Col>Different type of hello</Col>
          </Row>
        ) : (
          null
        )
      )
    )
  })}
}
```

This way your map is a bit cleaner, generating completely different rows instead of trying to nest everything in one condition.

Comment: @Ryan, glad you agree. Any luck on implementing what you want? I'm happy to help out if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Is React you should render (or return) a full component but you can do something like this to group the components and the return the full group wrapped by the `Row`:

```
    return (
      <>
        {items
          .reduce(
            (rows, key, index) =>
              (index % 3 === 0
                ? rows.push([key])
                : rows[rows.length - 1].push(key)) && rows,
            []
          )
          .map((items, idx) => (
            <Row key={idx}>
              {items.map(item => (
                <Col key={item} lg={3}>{item}</Col>
              ))}
            </Row>
          ))}
      </>
    );
```

The `reduce` is creating a two dimensional array with rows of 3 columns each.

A working example

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    return (
      <div>
        {myArr
          .reduce(
            (rows, key, index) =>
              (index % 3 === 0
                ? rows.push([key])
                : rows[rows.length - 1].push(key)) && rows,
            []
          )
          .map((items, idx) => console.log(items) || (
            <ol key={idx}>
              {items.map(item => console.log(item) || (
                <li key={item} lg={3}>{item}</li>
              ))}
            </ol>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```